# Data conversion from a .DAT file generated from COBOL

Tags: c++, cobol

I am trying to get a value from a .DAT file generated by a COBOL program.
But the problem is when I try to display the data to my c++ program.
I get a weird value like for 15.25 i get 960000.

My question is:
What's the preferred data type to import

```
PIC  S9999V99  COMP-5  VALUE +0

and

PIC  S9(7)     COMP-5  VALUE +0
```

My c++ code to import bytes to long

```
BOOL Import( LONG &nVal, INT nNumChars, FILE *pFile )
{
   char strVal[10];

   for ( int n = 0; n < (nNumChars); n++ )
   {
      if ( fread( &strVal[n], 1, 1, pFile ) != 1 )
      {
         return FALSE;
      }
   }

   strVal[n] = NULL;

   nVal = atol(strVal);

   return TRUE;
}
```

Hex of the first record

```
30 31 34 38 35 37 42 E7    03 00 00 00 00 00 00 31
32 2F 34 32 20 20 31 30    30 30 30 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
```

Comment: Comp-5 is a machine dependent format. I'd like to see an Hex dump of a full record in your question before answering.

Comment: What platform are you using?  What version of COBOL?

Comment: Im trying to read the .DAT file on a Windows CE (HPC2000) C++ program. I don't know what version of COBOL this file came from. Both fields (i believe) are 4 bytes.

Comment: Just write down a Hex dump of one record. Nobody will be able to answer correctly without that

Comment: You seem to be expecting a text format for numbers.  COBOL does indeed use those (or did back when I was using it), but uses several other formats as well.  COMP-5 seems to be standard binary data, so try reading as a regular four-byte integer.  Remember that the decimal points are typically implied, and 15.25 is probably 1525 with the compiler maintaining the decimal point.

Comment: Do you know what that first record is supposed to produce?  It looks like in ASCII it's "014857B?2/42  10        ???????1000      " where ? are outside the standard 96 ASCII printable characters. No sign of a 1525.  This does suggest it's using a text format, but you're not finding the end of the number correctly.

Comment: I'm able to get the first and the last values but Im having trouble retrieving the values in the middle (the 2 things above)

Comment: @David Yep. Seems the file is not what the OP described

Comment: @RyanA post the Hex dump of "good" values too.

Comment: @belisarius All of them are similar to that. I have no clue which one is good (if there are any) but based on my display testing all of them are "bad".

Comment: @RyanA Please post the **FD** records of the COBOL program. The data in the file is not what you are describing, but probably is valid ASCII and binary data with another FD format.

Answer (score 2):

This is the record you are trying to read:

```
  0  1  4  8  5  7  B --    -- -- --  z e r o e s 1    2  / 4  2   b  b  1  0

 30 31 34 38 35 37 42 E7    03 00 00 00 00 00 00 31   32 2F 34 32 20 20 31 30 
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
  0  0  0  b  b  b  b  b     b  b  b  b  b  b  b  b  

 30 30 30 20 20 20 20 20    20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
```

Where

```
b means whitespace  

zeroes are binary zeros

-- is a BINARY NUMBER COMP-5 and reversed (000003E7) == 999
```

So, no trace of your 1525, but perhaps this may help you to identify the contents. **Look at that "999"!**

HTH!

Comment: My bets are with you on this one. However, we are always taking a leap of faith when decoding data without the original record layout. Some of those alpha like character sequences may also be binary numbers, which just by accident, map to ascii characters too (best to look a several records). Another thing the OP should watch out for is that COBOL applications often use multiply defined record layouts so different records from the same file may have different record layouts.

Comment: @NealB Of course answering with partial information is always a risk. This one is half guessing, but it's my best guess with the info provided. Trying to interface two completely different systems used to be a common task years ago, but seems some tricks of the trade are being lost as generations of programmers work always on homogeneous configurations or with DBs only.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't enough information in your question to answer it.

The thing to do, is look at the program that generated the data file, and replicate the structures in there.

Answer (score 0):

As previously authors have stated, more inormation is needed; namely which **Cobol Compiler**; and the **Cobol Copybook** (or portion there of) would be useful.

But Reading in as a char array and using atol is probably wrong.

For most Cobol compilers (RM Cobol is different) you would

- Read as byte array
- Calculate from the byte array. For a 2 byte positive number you could

  long val = byte_array[0] * 256 +  byte_array[1]     /* Big Ending */
  long val = byte_array[0] +  byte_array[1] * 256     /* little Ending */

**Note:** the * 256 should be shift 8 bits but I do not rember the C shift operators

---

The V in Pic 99V99 is an assumed decimal place i.e.
 You will need to add the following calculation to the code

```
 double ret_val = long_val / 10      /* if  pic p(?)V9 */
 double ret_val = long_val / 100     /* if  pic p(?)V99 */
 double ret_val = long_val / 1000    /* if  pic p(?)V999 */
 double ret_val = long_val / 10000   /* if  pic p(?)V9990 */
```

to get the real Value.

**Note:** There are some editors that can display Cobol Data Files using a Cobol
Copybook (Depends which version of Cobol though).

Answer (score 0):

`PIC  S9(7)     COMP-5  VALUE +0`

The [`COMP-5`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzasb/sc092539388.htm) means that the value is stored in binary.  (You may need to swap bytes, depending on platform.)  The `S` means the field is signed (probably two's complement).  The `9(7)` means the field must have room for values up to ±9999999, which requires 4 bytes (1 sign bit + 24 value bits + 7 padding bits).  So the equivalent C data type is `int32_t`.

`PIC  S9999V99  COMP-5  VALUE +0`

`V` is an implicit decimal place.  Anything a COBOL program puts in it gets scaled by 100 behind the scenes (e.g., 15.25 gets stored as 001525, 16 gets stored as 001600, etc.).  In C++, you'll have to do this scaling yourself.

I'd normally use `double` for the external data type, but two decimal places strongly suggests dollars and cents, for which you should use a decimal type if one is available.

```
30 31 34 38 35 37 42 E7    03 00 00 00 00 00 00 31
32 2F 34 32 20 20 31 30    30 30 30 20 20 20 20 20
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
```

This looks like the ASCII string `014857B�␃␀␀␀␀␀␀12/42  10000`, which would suggest `DISPLAY` rather than `COMP-5` numbers.  Are you sure you're looking at the right part of the record?